# Add calendar event to custom calendar according to the event time - Angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I created a calendar in angular, each div getting a day/date value & time value

```
 <div  *ngFor="let day of weekDaysArray" class="calendar-table__week-days">
      <div *ngFor="let time of workingHoursArray; let i = index" class="calendar-table__week-days__slots"
        [ngClass]="{'hour-square-class': time.includes('00', 2) && i != 0 }"  (mousemove)="onMouseHover($event, day, time)" (mouseout)="onMouseOut()">  

      </div>
    </div>
```

Example for values inside the div:

```
    day = "Monday 5/11/2"
    time = "12:00"
--------------------------
    day = "Monday 5/11/2018"
    time = "12:15"   
--------------------------
    day = "Tuesday 6/11/2018"
    time = "18:15"
```

[**Result**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIiTT.png) *(In RTL sorry)*

Now i will be having an array of event objects when each object will look something like this:

```
  public event = {
    startTime: '08:30',
    endTime: '10:00',
    date: '01/11/2018',
    eventName: 'Take a walk in the park'
  }
```

So what i trying to achieve that each event will be displayed like this:
[**Wanted result**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f125.jpg)

In the last couple of days i am breaking my head how can i achieve this result, so any suggestion / direction how can i do it will be appreciated.